# Partner Authentication Failed

Tags: php, drupal-7, docusignapi

Does the **Developer's Integrator Key** expire after a certain period of time? And if so, is there a way to reset it without going through registration again? I am testing some rest calls and the response I received was:

> "errorCode": "PARTNER AUTHENTICATION FAILED" "message": "The specified
>   integrator key was not found or disabled. An integrator key was not
>   specified."

Answer (score 1):

Integrator Keys do not expire.  There must be something else going on.  You should figure out what web service call is being made and with what key.  Also you might have gotten a key from our developer's sandbox and started pointing to production in which case the key is not enabled there.

Comment: Correct. There was a CR in there that was causing the problem

Comment: Correct meaning that's the answer? :)